# Not printing all row values in excel sheet in Java

Tags: java, excel, selenium, read-data

When im trying to read and print all row value from excel sheet,one-row value is not printing, please check the below code

```
File src = new File("C:\\Users\\zuzu\\Desktop\\chat.xlsx");
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(src);
XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
XSSFSheet sheet1= wb.getSheetAt(0);

int rowcount = sheet1.getLastRowNum();

System.out.println("Total row is " +rowcount );
 for(int i=0;i<rowcount;i++)
            {
                String data0 =sheet1.getRow(i).getCell(0).getStringCellValue();
                System.out.println("values are "+data0);

            }
```

Output is:

```
Total row is 61
values are Name
values are ram1
values are ram2
values are ram3
values are ram4
values are ram5
```

ram 6 is not printed

Comment: Use a Debugger to find out what is happening

Comment: not reading the 7 th value in row

Comment: sorry my comment was wrong: **use a Debugger to find out why**

Comment: What is the format of value at row7; is it String or any different?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You are missing an equal on your for statement:

```
for(int i=0;i<=rowcount;i++)

   `
```